# wstringstream default format flag

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert 3 byte double to string. Following is my code.

```
    double b = 0xFFFFFF;    
std::wstring ss;
std::wstringstream sOut;

    sOut << b;  
    ss = boost::lexical_cast<std::wstring>(sOut.str());
```

I expect output to be 16777215. But "ss" has the value 1.67772e+007.

However when I use "fixed" flag, I get the expected output.

```
sOut << std::fixed
```

My question is whether wstringstream has "scientific" flag by default ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All streams (not just `wstringstream`) have floating-point formatting flags set to `ios_base::defaultfloat` by default, which requests the formatting you're observing, which is equivalent to `printf`'s conversion specifier `%g`.

To quote C's description of %g

> A double argument representing a floating-point number is converted in style f or e (or in style F or E in the case of a G conversion specifier), depending on the value converted and the precision. Let P equal the precision if nonzero, 6 if the precision is omitted, or 1 if the precision is zero. Then, if a conversion with style E would have an exponent of X:
>
> - if P > X >= -4, the conversion is with style f (or F) and precision P - (X + 1).
> - otherwise, the conversion is with style e (or E) and precision P - 1.

In your case, "the style e" is selected.